# Do I use the FV function in Excel correctly?

Tags: microsoft-excel, finance

**My task**: Create a table:

Calculate what the revenues of e-trading will be after five years at 15 percent interest rate if we now have 15 000 EUR. Use the FV function from the Financial Group in Excel.

**My resolution**: =FV( 15%; 5; 0; -15000).

**My question**: Is it correct?

I know the task lacks information whether the interest rate is per month or per year. I calculate it as 'per year'. My question is orientated more on the usage of the FV function. I, for example, do not understand why '-15000' and not '15000'. Also why the third parameter has to be 0? Maybe I do it wrong.

Please help me solve it! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Heh.. I would like to answer the question but I couldn't afford MS Office 2010. :(

Comment: @Shiki The beta is still available until October I think

Comment: Oh ..well.. if no answer will come I'll install it and verify my answer if its correct or not.

Comment: this is not about office-2010. I'm sorry for the wrong tag. I'm pretty sure it will work on 97 as well. I don't know whether I use the function the way I have to(the task).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good to me.  The answer is equal to `15000*1.15^5`, which is how I would calculate it by hand.  In these types of functions (present value, future value, rate of return) a negative value generally denotes a payment into the investment, while a positive value indicates what you withdraw from the investment.

The third parameter is the payment made each period (a period being a year, they way you've set things up).  So if you put money in, or took money out, each year, you would have a non-zero value there.

I noticed that you used semicolons (`;`) between your parameters.  In my Excel 2007, I have to use commas (`,`).  Maybe that's a configuration or internationalization difference.